# Run executable on all specified PCs via GPO

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I need to run certain exe or msi file at certain time on all specified PCs.

Since PC count may be very high, its preferable to do this via GPO.

All solutions for GPO I've found require rebooting all affected PCs to apply new GPO policy, but in my case rebooting every time I need to run this piece of software is highly undesirable and will make software less useful -
it is audit-related and inspects PC RAM among other things.

I've found solution via psexec, but it involves writing script, specifying needed PCs manually and specifying accounts and passwords, its not user-friendly and doesn't properly utilize AD infrastructure.

Is there some way to propagate GPO changes immediately w/out reboot or set taskschedule items on all machines in some centralized manner?

Comment: GPO doesn't require a reboot to apply most settings, including scheduled tasks.